# django: date picker drop down list doesn't reflect the filtered date range

Tags: python, django, datetimepicker

I used a datetime picker and want to assign a min/max date from the database "date_new" column. But the templates' drop down list still doesn't show the filtered date range (mindate-max datae).

Please advise on the change. Thanks in advance.

**forms.py**

```
from django.db.models import Min,Max

class Meta:
    model = XXX
    fields = (....,'start_date',....)
    widgets = {
           'start_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker',
               'data-min':Result.objects.all().aggregate(Min('date_new'))['date_new__min'],
               'data-max':Result.objects.all().aggregate(Max('date_new'))['date_new__max']             
            }
```

**html snippet**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
     $('.date-picker').datepicker(
                    {
                        dateFormat: "yy/mm",
                        changeMonth: true,
                        changeYear: true,
                        showButtonPanel: true,
                        minDate: $(this).data-min, <!--Here correct or not?---->
                        maxDate: $(this).data-max,
                        onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
                          ........................
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `:Result.objects.aggregate(Min('date_new'))` or `Result.objects.all().aggregate(Min('date_new'))`

Comment: Hi@xiaohen, sorry for the stupid mistake, but after correcting like this. Even though without error alert, but in the html dropdown list, it still not show the filteredresult. Do you think if I need to change my html?

Comment: @Elena. firstly, is the filter result right? "data-min" and data('min') is matched?